# AWS Cloudformation - reverse engineer an existing resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

Initially a while back created a cloudformation template to create multiple services on a given cluster, setup a aurora rds, redis and a load balancer.

The template was broken so i had to do various manual changes to get it working:

- redis was created on the default vpc so had to manually do vpc - vpc peering
- added https port forwarding on my alb
- cors and various arn inline roles for the s3 bucket
- and potentially dozen or so other changes

In the process of rewriting the cloudformation stack so my question is:

1. Is there a way using the aws cli to reverse engineer my current alb, rds, s3 to get a cloud formation formation template for each them?.

- so then i would be able to compare the cloud formation template with the new own and adjust it.

2. Or is there a way to compare the current cloudformation stack with the current state of the resources and reverse engineer it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems as [former2](https://github.com/iann0036/former2) would be the best solution to your use-case:

> Generate CloudFormation / Terraform / Troposphere templates from your existing AWS resources

Answer (score 0):

Without using a third-party solution, you can usually generate CloudFormation by simply using the appropriate `describe` command from the AWS CLI, and then:

- Prepend the CloudFormation resource name
- Remove any JSON fields that are not part of the CloudFormation syntax

For example, using only AWS CLI and [JQ](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) to generate CloudFormation for a DynamoDb table:

```
aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name MyTable | \
  jq '{"Type":"AWS::DynamoDB::Table","Properties": .Table } | 
    del(
      .Properties.CreationDateTime,
      .Properties.TableArn, 
      .Properties.TableId, 
      .Properties.ItemCount, 
      .Properties.TableSizeBytes, 
      .Properties.TableStatus, 
      .Properties.ProvisionedThroughput.NumberOfDecreasesToday, 
      .Properties.ProvisionedThroughput.LastDecreaseDateTime)'
```

This will output something like the following:

```
{
  "Type": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
  "Properties": {
    "AttributeDefinitions": [
      {
        "AttributeName": "someAttribute",
        "AttributeType": "S"
      }
    ],
    "TableName": "MyTable",
    "KeySchema": [
      {
        "AttributeName": "someAttribute",
        "KeyType": "HASH"
      }
    ],
    "ProvisionedThroughput": {
      "ReadCapacityUnits": 1,
      "WriteCapacityUnits": 1
    },
    "DeletionProtectionEnabled": false
  }
}
```

If you prefer YAML to JSON, you could pipe this output through something like [cfn-flip](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cfn-template-flip) (just add `| cfn-flip` to the command above) and you'll get:

```
Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
Properties:
  AttributeDefinitions:
    - AttributeName: someAttribute
      AttributeType: S
  TableName: MyTable
  KeySchema:
    - AttributeName: someAttribute
      KeyType: HASH
  ProvisionedThroughput:
    ReadCapacityUnits: 1
    WriteCapacityUnits: 1
  DeletionProtectionEnabled: false
```